# Почему ViewModel пересоздается?

Tags: android, viewmodel, livedata

```
class GalleryViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val galleryRepository = GalleryRepositoryImpl()
    private val _galleryImagesData = MutableLiveData<List<ImageItem>>()
    val galleryImagesData:LiveData<List<ImageItem>> get() = _galleryImagesData
    init {
        Log.d("tag","zagruzka")
        getImagesFromGallery()
    }

    private fun getImagesFromGallery() {
        val dispose = galleryRepository.getImagesFromGallery(getApplication())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ paths ->
                _galleryImagesData.value =
                    paths.map { ImageItem(Status.SUCCESS, it.first, it.second, null) }
            }, {
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
    }
}
```

Вот так вот я делаю observe

```
galleryViewModel.galleryImagesData
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                adapter.setItems(it)
            })
```

И вот так вот получаю viewmodel в фрагменте в методе onViewCreated

```
private lateinit var galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel
galleryViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
```

Почему лог запускается после каждого поворота?

Comment: А если вместо `ViewModelProvider(this)` написать `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`?

Comment: он deprecated, но сейчас проверю UPD: ничего не поменялось

Comment: возможно стоит еще указать, что так я создаю фрагмент в активити:
`supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, GalleryFragment())
                .commit()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184560/12191177

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon а если я получаю информацию из savedInstanceState(возможно есть какое-то другое решение как сохранять какой фрагмент был последний открыт в активити, но я его не нашел) `gallery = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(GALLERY_KEY) ?: true
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, if (gallery) GalleryFragment() else URLsFragment())
                .commit()`

Comment: Можно привязать viewmodel к активити `ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)`, но, конечно, она будет существовать на протяжении жизни активити. Можно использовать [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) для перехода по экранам вместо `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction() ....`, там таких проблем нет

Comment: Привязка помогла, но гляну еще navigation component, спасибо